# getHandler() NullPointerException when calling popBackstackImmediate() on a FragmentManager

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

I have this sime line in my code:

```
getChildFragmentManager().popBackstackImmediate();
```

It sometimes works, but often crashes. Here's the stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Handler android.support.v4.app.FragmentHostCallback.getHandler()' on a null object reference
          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1646)
          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:585)
          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate(FragmentManager.java:600)
          at marg.uk.fourthoffice.fragments.BCMasterDetailFragment.popBackStack(MyMasterDetailFragment.java:140)
          at marg.uk.fourthoffice.activities.BCOfficeActivity.onBackPressed(MainActivity.java:173)
          at marg.uk.fourthoffice.fragments.BCSwipeableCardsFragment$1.onClick(MyOtherFragment.java:189)
```

Any idea where could be an issue?

Comment: did you read [this](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=183920)

Comment: I did, but it looks like there is no solution there. I was hoping someone here found a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that there was an error in my code.

I can't show an example because there were a bunch of issues with my Activity-Fragment architecture, but the main issue was that getChildFragmentManager was actually empty and it was being called from the wrong fragment.

This was happening on a tablet (dual pane layout) where there were 4+ fragments being alive at the same time. This was being called on the wrong fragment.

So if you are experiencing a similar issue, you might have multiple instances of the same fragment in memory. Make sure that you are calling this method from the correct instance.

Comment: For me, it happened because of a wrong super method call. The overridden onStop() method was calling `super.onDestroy()` somehow and changing that to `super.onStop()` fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

```js
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
//     super.onBackPressed();
       finish();
}
```

Just comment **super()** method and write **finish()** instead